# Word for someone quick to blame others

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is a single word to describe a person who is quick to blame others or the system in almost any situation, regardless of whether that is legitimate or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could call this person a *finger-pointer*, *buck-passer*, *scape-goater* or *blame-shifter*.

Alternatively, a *shirker* avoids things (usually work), or more generally a you could say they're a *crybaby* or are *unprofessional*.

Answer (score 4):

**Reprehending** is a good fit, but also...

an **Imputing** person or **Accusatory** or **Denunciatory** or **Condemnatory** / **Condemning** or **animadverter** (and so on)

(if accusations not true then **Aspersive** person or **Maligning** person)