# Adjective for a particular form of cavalier attitude

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm hoping to find a particular word to describe a variant of a cavalier attitude.

I need to describe the attitude of an individual who, knowing that they themselves have been irresponsible, express an impartiality towards the issue and also thrust the blame on someone else.

Such behavior would normally be found in extremely cold, distancing people who give off little emotion and who will uphold their own honor even if it comes at the expense of others. When something goes awry by their own hand, such an individual might coldly start barking orders at someone else to make it seem as if they had no role.

Is there a good adjective to describe this attitude?

Comment: Perhaps sociopathic?

Comment: I don't know if there is a word for precisely this in the english language. You might check these other questions: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372103/what-do-you-call-someone-who-refuses-to-acknowledge-their-wrongdoing, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185835/what-do-you-call-someone-who-always-puts-blame-on-others, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72649/word-for-someone-quick-to-blame-others