# Word for: a word which sufficiently describes a thing

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes when a word describes a thing or situation *completely*?

It is easy to come up with a word which is correct in a particular context, in the sense that the thing fits the definition of the word. But it's much more challenging to come up with a word that when used describes a thing entirely, in the sense that you could rely on that word alone to communicate the idea.

To put another way, what would you call it when there is a word which is *sufficient* to describe something to some desired level of detail?

Example sentence. "I am looking for a **desired single word** word for **thing/situation/idea**."

Ideally, this word would be specific to linguistics, rather than a generic term, like "equivalent" or "sufficient."

For a specific example, consider a definition of *deceive*:

> (of a person) cause (someone) to believe something that is not true, typically in order to gain some personal advantage.

Now consider the definition of *gaslight*:

> manipulate (someone) by psychological means into questioning their own sanity.

*Deceive* certainly doesn't seem incorrect to apply to the definition gaslight, but clearly it doesn't fully specify what gaslighting is. Another example is from a [recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387763/adjective-for-a-particular-form-of-cavalier-attitude), asking for a word for a specific kind of bullying, wherein a person never admits wrongdoing and insists that *others* are always in the wrong despite evidence to the contrary. A commenter [suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387763/adjective-for-a-particular-form-of-cavalier-attitude#comment913923_387763) "sociopathic," which doesn't fully capture the scenario, despite it probably being an appropriate label for this sort of person.

Comment: Even though you're asking for an English word for this concept, you may well get a more accurate response over at http://linguistics.stackexchange.com or  even http://philosophy.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was thinking that the Saussurean 'signifier' is in the right direction but informally  'le mot juste' might be just le mot juste.

Comment: Isn’t that the relationship between a word and its definition?

Comment: I don't think you've really thought this through. Even a term as apparently well-defining as 'fructose' refers to a substance that occurs in open-chain and cyclic forms, as well as stereoisomers (and a bottlefull of the stuff would be some complex mixture of these forms, together with traces of impurity). As for 'table', 'radiator', 'girl', 'car', 'hole', 'light', 'faith', 'word',  ... I believe all you can hope for is 'sufficiently characterising term' with context pointing to the level of definition aimed at.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand well your thought but it makes me think of the quarrel of universals
http://cura.free.fr/23phidec.html
Moreover Kant Tells us that de Noumenon or rather the "Thing in itself"  is an Unknowable reality.

Comment: @Baiwir Would that be paraphrasable by 'No word / sentence / essay is adequate to truly specify any real object / notion ...'?

Comment: No I don't think so. What is real is rational, Hegel says. On the other hand, what does   truth mean, where is it while de brain is only a receptor.     what is the true reality ? Reality might be actually true, but not really.

Comment: What you’re looking for is the “***appropriate***” word...

Comment: "alternate" , "substitute","equivalent", "backup" all suggest that you could swap one thing for another without changing the function.

Comment: @Tom22 - Given OP’s one-to-one mapping constraint there will be no alternate or equivalent. :-)

Comment: @Jim hmm... I'm not reading the request for "uniqueness" but instead "**unambiguous**" .  But Yes, he does use "one to one" mapping twice, which would mean that the thing could Only called one thing AND the thing could only be called one word.  Perhaps he could clarify that he means to use one to one in that way.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps I haven't given this enough thought, but not in the way you suggest: I specified that such a word addresses the situation to *some desired level of detail*. "Sufficiently characterising term" could be a definition for the word I am searching for.

Comment: @Jim "appropriate" is not quite enough. I added a more specific example that I think illustrates this word does not work.

Comment: @Tom22 I think "equivalent," "unambiguous," and "sufficient" are maybe the best options that have been suggested so far. But I'm looking for a linguistic term. And I think "one-to-one" is too strong. I will edit.

Comment: @Jim maybe simply a "defining word" is correct here.

Comment: @Evan - I just posted an answer along the same lines.

Comment: You also used  "Word for one-to-one mapping between: a word and what it's referring to...

Is there a word that describes when a word describes a thing or situation completely?" The fact that you've subsequently edited out this (I'd consider impossible-to-comply-with) constraint would seem to show that you have re-thought along the lines I said I considered necessary. And your original question/s was/were self-contradictory; I addressed one of the two thrusts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ridiculous that this is on hold. The question, at this point, is extremely detailed, and in any case a proper answer has been contributed, voted up, and accepted.

Comment: 'Seems obvious' indicates that the adjusted question should be on ELL if anywhere. Since you use 'definition' in the question, perhaps it would be best closed for lack of reasonable research.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I disagree. It seems obvious now, but hindsight is 20/20, as they say. Also, the question is "on hold" apparently due to lack of clarity, not lack of research (if that is an available reason - I don't know because I don't yet have the reputation). I'm struck by the zeal with which some users seek to cull questions. I do not find it to be constructive. Close it if you want.

Comment: The word for this is ‘apposite’ which means ‘apt in the circumstances or in relation to something.
"an apposite quotation"
synonyms: appropriate, suitable, fitting, apt, befitting;.  And is, itself, in this case - apposite!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider ***definitive***

Defined by [The American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/definitive) as:

> - Serving to define or identify as distinct from others
> - satisfying all criteria

Comment: Yes, perfect. Seems obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I think about is "**concept**" which is already in the mind     and speaks for itself :

1. an idea, esp an abstract idea: the concepts of biology.
2. (Philosophy) philosophy a general idea or notion that corresponds to some class of entities                                                           and that consists of the characteristic or essential features of the class
3. (Philosophy) philosophy
   a. the conjunction of all the characteristic features of something
   b. a theoretical construct within some theory
   c. a directly intuited object of thought
   d. the meaning of a predicate
   http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concept